# WordPress scroll jitter when scrolling towards the end

Tags: wordpress, scroll, jitter

I'm having an issue with my site where on some pages I'm getting a jitter when scrolling to the bottom of the page and it forces me back up to the top before I can even see the footer?

Here's an example of a page it happens on

http://babylonradio.com/groups/

but on my developer page where I have something similar it doesn't happen so I'm very confused, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because the sticky nav bar was interfering with the length of the page and when the page scrolled down the sticky nav bar would try to stick to the top of the page but wouldn't have enough room as the length of the page wasn't enough